# How to replace some excel row by pattern

Tags: excel, regex, replace

masters

I have too wide rows in MS Excel
Values of cells looks like:

=some_formula!$**A**31 **|** =some_formula!$**A**31 ... **|**
=some_formula!$**B**31 **|** =some_formula!$**B**31 ... **|**
=some_formula!$**C**31...

What is the best and fastest way to replace all $**A31**, $**B31**, $**C31** ... etc on a row to $**A40**, $**B40**, $**C40**   etc..

I tried to use "find and replace", but it give possible to replace A, B, C...  one by one

Wanted somthing like $(?)31 -> $(1)40

Answer (score 0):

This is by using excel vba.

```
Sub CopyCells()
    Dim prevRow, newRow
    copyRow = 40
    targetRow = 31
    'Chr(65) = A, Chr(66) = B and so on
    'For i = 1 To 5 will mean that from column A to E
    'as I will be using Chr(64 + i) in the code
    For i = 1 To 5
        Range(Chr(64 + i) & targetRow).Value = Range(Chr(64 + i) & copyRow).Value
    Next
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! Hm... how can I set one special row for replace cell's formulas in this script? (not full sheet)

Comment: Oh okay okay sorry I misread your post. I thought you would only be copying the content. Do you know how to setup a module in excel macro (or excel vba)? I will be modifying the code though to suit your needs

Comment: No, I don't know excel. Sorry for my english =\

Answer (score 0):

I think it will be easier to Find & Replace the 31 with a 40 than to write a bunch of code.  Is it likely that there is a 31 that is NOT a row reference in your formula?

Comment: Thanks! Allready done as you said in this case, but I think it isn't secure replace numbers with no some unique simbols around